# use CASE inside a lock tables for multiples statements

Tags: mysql, case

I need some assistance from some good soul, I'm trying to create a mysql query (or execute some code) inside a lock tables block, based on some result I need to execute sub block 1 or the other, I was planing to use CASE for this so far I have this

```
SELECT @myRight := node.rgt, @myLeft := node.lft, @nivel := node.nivel_pag, @grp := node.grp
FROM `tbl_pages_temp` AS node, `tbl_pages_temp` AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt AND parent.id_pag = 38 AND node.grp =    parent.grp AND node.id_pag != parent.id_pag
ORDER BY node.lft DESC LIMIT 1;

#here I want to use CASE or something else so, if @grp > 1 then do updates/insert block1 otherwise do second block
#block 1
UPDATE tbl_pages_temp SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myRight;

UPDATE tbl_pages_temp SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myRight;

INSERT INTO tbl_pages_temp(menu_pag, lft, rgt, nivel_pag, grp) VALUES('GAME CONSOLES', @myRight + 1, @myRight + 2, @nivel + 1, @grp);

#block 2
UPDATE tbl_pages_temp SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myLeft;

UPDATE tbl_pages_temp SET lft = left + 2 WHERE lft > @myLeft;

INSERT INTO tbl_pages_temp(menu_pag, lft, rgt, nivel_pag, grp) VALUES('GAME CONSOLES', @myLeft + 1, @myLeft + 2, @nivel + 1, @grp);

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

I can't use store procedure on this DB, am I doing this right or there is a better way??
thanks!!!

My bad, yes the idea is to use one param or the other depending of the @grp value, yes I'm assuming the cose could more compact, let me try both answers, both looks good

Comment: Is the SQL correct? Seems strange with a sudden `lft > @myRight` comparison, and is `left` the same as `lft`? Are the updates supposed to be the same in both cases, just the insert diffing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that the difference in the updates are just typos, and only the `INSERT` should differ. In that case, fairly simple to do both cases with a single statement;

```
INSERT INTO tbl_pages_temp(menu_pag, lft, rgt, nivel_pag, grp) 
    VALUES('GAME CONSOLES', 
           CASE WHEN @grp > 1 THEN @myRight + 1 ELSE @myLeft + 1 END,
           CASE WHEN @grp > 1 THEN @myRight + 2 ELSE @myLeft + 2 END,
           @nivel + 1, @grp);
```